# Why "gofmt -d" gives "computing diff: exec: "diff": executable file not found in %PATH%" error on windows?

Tags: go

I would like to see what mistakes I made in my golang files. In order to figure it out, I issue a command like this:

```
gofmt -d myfile.go
```

According to the `gofmt --help` manual, it is supposed to list the diff of the current and the desired versions of the file. Instead of this, it produces this error message:

```
computing diff: exec: "diff": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 8):

The `gofmt` tool assumes the system has an installed and available `diff`. Unfortunately, this tool is not part of a standard Windows installation so you need to add it manually.

For most of us, the easiest way to add the path of the `diff` tool we already have on our computer. This is the one that has been installed as part of `git`. (If `git` hasn't been installed yet then do it at first.)

In order to solve this, you should issue a command from the DOS prompt in which you want to execute `gofmt`:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

(Maybe you need to change the path according to your `git` installation.)

For a more permanent solution, you should add the path of `diff.exe` to the PATH environment variable via the Control Panel.